# Append additional element to existing array getting error

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, append

In my head this should be pretty simple but for some reason its getting the better of me I must be too tired or its just so obvious. I have an array of items taken from the DB and I need to update some elements and I'm using a for loop to go through each element of the array that in this case holds four elements.

```
[16] => Array
        (
            [sku] => SKU14820
            [item] => Box of Shoes
            [desc] => Nice leather Shoes
            [price] => 66
        )
```

So I created my loop and started to go through each small array because the original array length can vary and the individual arrays can vary and i'm using the for loop to prepare my statement for mysqli updating of the db.

So each element in the smaller array needs to be assigned a binding_param so I thought the easiest way most likely not the nicest looking was to just check for isset and then append to that element the binding parameter.

```
 for($x=0;$x < count($checked);$x++){
            $bind_type = array();
            $sku = $checked[$x]['sku'];
            if(isset($checked[$x]['sku'])){

             $bind_type[0] = 's';
             print_r($bind_type);
            $checked[$x]['sku'][] = $bind_type;
         }
   }
```

I keep getting this error and I am stumped.. help much appreciated for which I suspect is an obvious error in my part....

```
>>Array
>>(
>>    [0] => s
>>)
>>
>>
>>Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings
```

Comment: I think `$checked[$x]['sku']` is a string, not an array right? Are you sure that this works? `$checked[$x]['sku'][] = $bind_type`

Comment: Can you show us an example of how your updated array should look like? is it something like this:

[16] => Array
        (
            [sku] => SKU14820
            [item] => Box of Shoes
            [desc] => Nice leather Shoes
            [price] => 66
            [bind_type] => s
)

Comment: Perhaps like this https://3v4l.org/D6Y79

Comment: I was driving to work and thought I may have fixed but alas not.... The idea to run through every element in the array and assign the binding_type in readiness to to a prepared statement to update. I changed the array to an associative array instead of numeric and this still doesn't work...

Comment: Think I the penny has dropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its much cleaner to use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for your use case. Im not sure how exactly you want to see your modified array. Assuming you want something like this:

```
array(
    'sku' => array('a', 'SKU14820'),
    'item' => 'Box of Shoes',
    'desc' => 'Nice leather Shoes',
    'price' => 66
)
```

The following code should do it for you:

```
$checked = array_map(function($item) {
    if (isset($item['sku'])) {
        $item['sku'] = ['s', $item['sku']];
    }
    return $item;
}, $checked);
```

Comment: Thanks it gave me the jolt of grey matter needed to fix it I wasn't fully understanding what I was doing in modifying my array to include the new element and your response pointed me in the right direction. The error I was getting was valid because I was stupid - lol

Comment: No problem. Glad to know I could help :)